# second order differential equation checks. Are these right?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I want to make sure I'm solving these differential equations correct. Is this right?

1. $$y" - 2y' - 3y = 0$$ with initial conditions: $y(0) = 2$ and $y'(0) = 2$

so the auxiliary equation:

$$r^2 - 2r -3 = 0$$
$$(r + 1)(r-3) = 0$$
so $r = -1, 3$

so generally: $$y = c_1e^{-x} + c_2e^{3x}$$

if $y(0) = 2 = c_1 + c_2$ and $y'(0) = 2 = -c_1 + 3c_2$ then $c_2 = 1$ and $c_1 = 1$

so the solution given the initial conditions is:

$$y = e^{-x} + e^{3x}$$

Is that right?

2. I'm a bit stuck on this one:

$$3y" + 4y' - 3y = 0$$

the auxiliary equation is:

$$3r^2 + 4r -3 = 0$$

The roots can't be found by factoring easily so I'll use the quadratic:

$$r = \frac{-4 \pm \sqrt{16 - 4(3)(-3)}}{6}$$

$$r = \frac{-4 \pm \sqrt{16 + 36}}{6}$$

$$r = \frac{-2}{3} \pm \frac{2 \sqrt{13}}{3}$$

so is the solution just:

$$y = c_1e^{r_1x} + c_2e^{r_2x}$$

where r1 and r2 are just the two roots found by solving the quadratic?

Answer (score 1):

The first solution is indeed correct. There's a slight error in the second, purely arithmetical:

$$3r^2 +4r - 3 = 0 \implies r = \frac{-4 \pm \sqrt{52}}{6} = \frac{-4 \pm 2\sqrt{13}}{6} = \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{13}}{3}$$

When factoring out $\sqrt{52} = \sqrt{4} \cdot \sqrt{13}$, it seems you left it as just $4$ (as I did before this edit) instead of $2$. Thus your $r$'s should have $\sqrt{13}$, not double it.

Purely arithmetical and an easy oversight. Like I said, I did it too. Your overall idea **is** correct however for the second one.

---

Other than this, if I had to nitpick, if this is for, say, a school assignment, I would include how you solved for the $c_1,c_2$ on the assignment. Your values *are* right, it's largely a matter of making it easier to follow for whoever's reading. Might be just a personal thing though.

Also, note that you can always check these by plugging in the $y$ you get into the differential equation and checking, and also ensuring that the initial conditions are indeed met if applicable. Always a good paranoia check.

---

*Edit:*

While far from infallible, Wolfram Alpha also proves to be a good paranoia check. For example, the solutions for the [first problem](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%27%27+-+2y%27+-+3y+%3D+0,+y(0)%3Dy%27(0)%3D2) and [second problem](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+3y%27%27+%2B+4y%27+-+3y+%3D+0) can be found there. If for some reason the expressions were to differ significantly from yours, that would be a sign of your derivation being wrong.

*In this case, that's how I noticed both you and I were wrong in solving the second problem, since I could not see where that pesky $2$ disappeared to. :p*

Comment: EDIT: I derped and made the same mistake as you! Will fix.

Comment: And fixed, with explanation to boot. Sorry for the trouble I might have initially caused.